# Auth0.js: Callback function after access_token refresh

Tags: next.js, auth0, next-auth

I have a Next.js application where I am integrating Auth0. In the code below, `afterCallback` function is being called every time the user login, but not after the access_token gets refresh. Is there any way I can call a callback function every time the access_token gets refresh?

```
import { AfterCallbackPageRoute, handleAuth, handleCallback } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";    
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { decodeJwt } from "jose";

export const afterCallback: AfterCallbackPageRoute = (_req, _res, session) => {
  if (session.accessToken) {
    const decoded = decodeJwt(session.accessToken);
    if (typeof decoded === "object") {      
      session.user.isEmployee = decoded["<employee-claim>"];
    }
  }
  return session;
};   
    
export default handleAuth({
  async callback(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    try {
      await handleCallback(req, res, { afterCallback });          
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).end();
    }
  },
});
```